# Python styling results of SQL query with xlsxWriter

Tags: python, sql, styling, xlsxwriter

I am reading an Excel spreadsheet into sqlite3 so that I can run SQL queries - then I am writing it back to Excel via xlsxWriter so that I can style the columns. Everything works fine except the SQL query which is not being executed. Any help would be welcome. Thank you.

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import xlsxwriter
import os





file = '/Volumes/XCODE_UI/PYTHON/mypython/vaultlight.xlsx'
output = 'output.xlsx'

engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=False)
df = pd.read_excel(file,sheet_name='50000')
df["Total_sales"] = df['Sold'] * df['Price']
df["Margin"] = (df['Price'] - df['Cost']) / df["Price"]


df.to_sql('data', engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)

results = engine.execute("Select * from data where Country = 'India'")


writer_orig = pd.ExcelWriter('myTest.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer_orig, index=False, sheet_name='India')



workbook = writer_orig.book
worksheet = writer_orig.sheets['India']


money_fmt = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '£#,##0.00', 'bold': True})
percent_fmt = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0.0%', 'bold': True})

worksheet.set_column('D:F', 12, money_fmt)
worksheet.set_column('G:G', 12, percent_fmt)

writer_orig.save()
```

Comment: Is there any error your facing while executing SQL query? I doubt if while creating df it might not have country column or not able to read it properly as country column.

Comment: No I don't get any errors at all - the only thing I can think is that the 'results' are not being called anywhere. I would know where to put them though

Answer (score 1):

I cracked it:-

```
file = '/Volumes/XCODE_UI/PYTHON/mypython/vaultlight.xlsx'
output = 'myTest.xlsx'

engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=False)
df = pd.read_excel(file,sheet_name='50000')
df["Total_sales"] = df['Sold'] * df['Price']
df["Margin"] = (df['Price'] - df['Cost']) / df["Price"]

df.to_sql('data', engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)
results = engine.execute("Select * from data where Country = 'India'")
final=pd.DataFrame(results, columns=df.columns)

print(final)
writer_orig = pd.ExcelWriter('myTest.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
final.to_excel(writer_orig, index=False, sheet_name='India')

workbook = writer_orig.book
worksheet = writer_orig.sheets['India']

money_fmt = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '£#,##0.00', 'bold': True})
percent_fmt = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0.0%', 'bold': True})

worksheet.set_column('D:F', 12, money_fmt)
worksheet.set_column('G:G', 12, percent_fmt)

writer_orig.save()
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. Could you explain why this works and the original doesn't?

Comment: Yes, in the original I made SQL query (results) but didn't write then anywhere - so used this 'final=pd.DataFrame(results, columns=df.columns)' to write the results to a dataframe and then that dataframe to excel in 'final.to_excel(writer_orig, index=False, sheet_name='India')'